# Fault in some of my functions regarding List C++

Tags: c++, list, inheritance, copying

I use, the ICircularDoubleDirectedList for a class structure, then my List inherits from this and that file can you find further down. I use a file to test the deep copying on the list, but the thing is that it passes all the test except the one at the end where it's supposed to delete all the data.

I have tested all my functions and they pass the test so I have no clue where I can find the solution :/

I know it might be a lot to look at and I can't really describe how happy I would be if someone would help me out! :D

This is the design structure for my List:

```
#ifndef ICDDLIST_H
#define ICDDLIST_H


template <typename T>
class ICircularDoubleDirectedList
{
public:
    static enum direction{FORWARD, BACKWARD};
    virtual ~ICircularDoubleDirectedList() {};                      //gjord
    virtual void addAtCurrent(const T& element) = 0;                //gjord
    virtual T& getElementAtCurrent() const = 0;                     //gjord
    virtual bool removeAtCurrent(const T& element) = 0;                             
    virtual int size() const = 0;                                   //gjord
    virtual void changeDirection() = 0;                             //gjord     
    virtual void moveCurrent() = 0;                                 //gjord
    virtual typename direction getCurrentDirection() const = 0;     //gjord
};

#endif

___________________________________________________________________________
```

Here is my definition and declarations. Yes, I know they should be in two different header and .cpp files, but it's easier to test if they are in the same I think.

```
#ifndef DOUBLELIST_H
#define DOUBLELIST_H

#include "ICircularDoubleDirectedList.h"

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class CircularDoubleDirectedList : public ICircularDoubleDirectedList <T>{

private:

    class Node{
    public:

        T data;
        Node *neighbors[2];

        Node(const T& element);
        Node(){};
        ~Node(){};


    };

    direction NodeDirection = FORWARD;
    Node *current;
    int sizeOfList;

public:

    CircularDoubleDirectedList();
    CircularDoubleDirectedList(const CircularDoubleDirectedList &other);
    ~CircularDoubleDirectedList();

    virtual void addAtCurrent(const T& element);

    T& getElementAtCurrent() const;
    bool removeAtCurrent(const T& element);
    int size() const;
    void changeDirection();
    void moveCurrent();
    typename direction getCurrentDirection() const;


    bool operator=(const CircularDoubleDirectedList &other);


};




template <typename T>
CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::Node::Node(const T& element){

    data = element;

}

template <typename T>
CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::~CircularDoubleDirectedList(){

    if (this->size() != 0){
        while (0 < this->sizeOfList){
            this->removeAtCurrent(this->getElementAtCurrent());
        }
    }
    //this->current = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::CircularDoubleDirectedList(){

    NodeDirection = FORWARD;
    sizeOfList = 0;
    current = nullptr;

}

template <typename T>
CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::CircularDoubleDirectedList(const CircularDoubleDirectedList &other){

    this->NodeDirection = other.NodeDirection;
    this->current = other.current;
    this->sizeOfList = 0;

    if (other.sizeOfList != 0){
        Node *counter = other.current;

        for (int x = 0; x < other.sizeOfList; x++){
            counter = counter->neighbors[BACKWARD];
            this->addAtCurrent(counter->data);
        }
    }
    else{
        this->current = nullptr;
    }

}




template <typename T>
void CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::addAtCurrent(const T& element){

    Node *temp = new Node(element);

    if (current == nullptr){
        current = temp;
        temp->neighbors[FORWARD] = temp;
        temp->neighbors[BACKWARD] = temp;


    }

    else{
        temp->neighbors[FORWARD] = current;
        temp->neighbors[BACKWARD] = current->neighbors[BACKWARD];
        temp->neighbors[BACKWARD]->neighbors[FORWARD] = temp;

        current->neighbors[BACKWARD] = temp;

        current = temp;
    }

    ++sizeOfList;

}

template <typename T>
T& CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::getElementAtCurrent() const{

    if (sizeOfList <= 0){
        throw "Exeption: call of getElementAtCurrent on empty list";
    }

    else{
        return current->data;
    }

}



template <typename T>                   //INTE FEL PÅ
bool CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::removeAtCurrent(const T& element){                      
    bool success = false;

    Node *temp = this->current;

    int x = 0;
    if(sizeOfList <= 0){
        throw "Exeption: call of removeAtCurrent on empty list";
    }

    else if (sizeOfList==1 && current->data==element){
        delete current;
        this->current = nullptr;
        this->sizeOfList--;
        success = true;
    }

    while(x<this->sizeOfList && success==false ) {
        if (temp->data == element){
            if (temp == this->current){
                this->moveCurrent();
            }

            temp->neighbors[BACKWARD]->neighbors[FORWARD] = temp->neighbors[FORWARD];
            temp->neighbors[FORWARD]->neighbors[BACKWARD] = temp->neighbors[BACKWARD];

            delete temp;
            this->sizeOfList--;
            success = true;


        }
        else{
            temp = temp->neighbors[FORWARD];
        }
        x++;
    }

    return success;
}

template <typename T>
int CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::size() const{

    return sizeOfList;

}

template <typename T>
void CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::changeDirection(){


    if (NodeDirection == FORWARD){
        NodeDirection = BACKWARD;
    }
    else
        NodeDirection = FORWARD;

}


template <typename T>
void CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::moveCurrent(){

    if (NodeDirection == FORWARD && sizeOfList>0){
        current = current->neighbors[FORWARD];
    }
    else if (NodeDirection == BACKWARD && sizeOfList>0){
        current = current->neighbors[BACKWARD];
    }
    else{
        throw "Exception: call of moveCurrent on empty list";
    }
}

template <typename T>
typename ICircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::direction CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::getCurrentDirection() const{

    return NodeDirection;

}



template <typename T>   //inte fel på
bool CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::operator=(const CircularDoubleDirectedList &other){


    if (&other == this){
        return true;
    }

    if (this->size() != 0){
        Node *temp1 = this->current;
        T temp2;

        while (0 < this->sizeOfList){
            temp2 = temp1->data;
            temp1 = temp1->neighbors[FORWARD];
            this->removeAtCurrent(temp2);
        }
        this->current = nullptr;
    }

    this->NodeDirection = other.NodeDirection;

    if (other.size() > 0){

        Node *counter = other.current;

        for (int x = 0; x < other.size(); x++){
            counter = counter->neighbors[BACKWARD];
            this->addAtCurrent(counter->data);
        }
    }
    else{
        this->current = nullptr;
    }

    return true;

}




#endif
```

---

And this is the file I use to test my List:

```
#include "CircularDoubleDirectedList.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
void printList(CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>& list)
{
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<list.getElementAtCurrent()<<" ";
        list.moveCurrent();
    }
}

template <typename T>
void test(CircularDoubleDirectedList<T> list)
{
    list.addAtCurrent(55);
}

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    CircularDoubleDirectedList<int> aList;
    CircularDoubleDirectedList<int> bList = aList;

    cout<<"******** Testing copy constructor on empty list ********"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Expected output: \nElements in aList: \nElements in bList"<<endl<<endl<<"Your output: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Elements in aList ";
    printList(aList);

    cout<<endl<<"Elements in bList ";
    printList(bList);
    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
    cout<<endl<<"******** Testing copy constructor on list with content ********"<<endl;

    aList.addAtCurrent(10);
    aList.addAtCurrent(20);

    CircularDoubleDirectedList<int> cList = aList;

    cout<<endl<<"Expected output: \nElements in aList 20 10\nElements in cList 20 10"<<endl<<endl<<"Your output: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Elements in aList ";
    printList(aList);

    cout<<endl<<"Elements in cList ";
    printList(cList);

    aList.removeAtCurrent(20);
    cList.addAtCurrent(5);

    cout<<endl<<endl<<"Expected output: \nElements in cList 5 20 10"<<endl<<endl<<"Your output: "<<endl;

    test(cList);

    cout<<"Elements in cList ";
    printList(cList);

    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");

    CircularDoubleDirectedList<int> dList;
    CircularDoubleDirectedList<int> eList;


    cout<<endl<<endl<<"******** Testing assignment operator on empty list ********"<<endl;
    dList = eList;
    cout<<endl<<"Expected output: \nElements in dList \nElements in eList"<<endl<<endl<<"Your output: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Elements in dList ";
    printList(dList);

    cout<<endl<<"Elements in eList ";
    printList(eList);
    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");

    cout<<endl<<endl<<"**** Testing assignment operator on list with content assigned empty list****"<<endl;
    eList.addAtCurrent(20);
    eList.addAtCurrent(10);

    eList = dList;

    cout<<endl<<"Expected output: \nElements in dList\nElements in eList"<<endl<<endl<<"Your output: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Elements in dList ";
    printList(dList);

    cout<<endl<<"Elements in eList ";
    printList(eList);
    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<endl<<"***** Testing assignment operator on empty list assigned list with content *****"<<endl;
    eList.addAtCurrent(20);
    eList.addAtCurrent(10);

    dList = eList;

    cout<<"Expected output: \nElements in dList 10 20 \nElements in eList 10 20"<<endl<<endl<<"Your output: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Elements in dList ";
    printList(dList);

    cout<<endl<<"Elements in eList ";
    printList(eList);
    cout<<endl;

    system("pause");

    dList.addAtCurrent(5);
    eList.removeAtCurrent(20);
    cout<<endl<<"Expected output: \nElements in dList 5 10 20 \nElements in eList 10"<<endl<<endl<<"Your output: "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Elements in dList ";
    printList(dList);

    cout<<endl<<"Elements in eList ";
    printList(eList);
    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");

    cout<<endl<<"***** Testing assignment operator on lists with content *****"<<endl;

    eList = dList;

    cout<<"Expected output: \nElements in dList 5 10 20 \nElements in eList 5 10 20"<<endl<<endl<<"Your output: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Elements in dList ";
    printList(dList);

    cout<<endl<<"Elements in eList ";
    printList(eList);
    cout<<endl;

    system("pause");

    eList.addAtCurrent(1);
    dList.removeAtCurrent(10);

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Expected output: \nElements in dList 5 20 \nElements in eList 1 5 10 20"<<endl<<endl<<"Your output: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Elements in dList ";
    printList(dList);

    cout<<endl<<"Elements in eList ";
    printList(eList);
    cout<<endl;

    system("pause");

    cout<<endl<<"***** Testing assignment operator on a list assigned itself *****"<<endl;

    dList = dList;

    cout<<endl<<"Expected output: \nElements in dList 5 20 "<<endl<<endl<<"Your output: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Elements in dList ";
    printList(dList);
    cout<<endl;

    system("pause");


    cout<<endl<<"***** Testing destructor of list *****"<<endl;


    ICircularDoubleDirectedList<int>* fList = new CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>();


    fList->addAtCurrent(100);           
    fList->addAtCurrent(50);


    delete fList;               //NÅgot fel här 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the output you expect, and the output you are getting?

Comment: While adding things like _Firstly, thank you for atleast watching this post_ looks nice, it's mostly a distraction, and it's better to just ask the question in as clear fashion as possible and reduce the non essential text to the bare minimum. Having to read a lot of text just in order to find the actual question might turn people away from even looking at it.

Comment: @n.m The thing is I get "Unhandled exception at 0x01086B2E in Restinlämning 1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFEEEFEF6.". After stepping through the program I can see that it can't read  temp->neighbors[BACKWARD]->neighbors[FORWARD] = temp->neighbors[FORWARD];
   temp->neighbors[FORWARD]->neighbors[BACKWARD] = temp->neighbors[BACKWARD];.

I belive I delete it somewhere else but I cant find it.

Comment: @jpw noted, will keep that in mind.

Comment: Your copy constructor and assignment operators are not written to do a copy.  For your case, there should be no `if` statements at all in those functions.   If there are, you're risking having a copy not being an actual copy of the passed-in object.  For example, your function(s) should not be doing this:  `if (this->size() != 0)`

Comment: @Prolle - `I have tested all my functions and they pass the test`  Obviously, they didn't pass the test, since you are reporting a problem.

Comment: @Prolle - `void test(CircularDoubleDirectedList<T> list)`  If you expected `list` to change after the function is called, it won't change.  You're passing 'list` by value -- any changes to `list` in that function will not be retained once the function returns.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Still same problem. Okey, did another test with another cpp file that didnt test deepcopying, and the functions it tried worked.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The problem is not in the "TestDeepCopyingofList", its somewhere in "CircularDoubleDirectedList".

Comment: @Prolle Your operator= should be returning an object, not `bool`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If I change it too: T& operator=(const CircularDoubleDirectedList &other); and return current->data but still get the same fault. 

If I comment out my whole destructor it passes the test but I have extencive memory leaks.

Comment: Also tried CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>& but same, cant access the "neighbors".

Comment: @Prolle - Please read my answer.  You implemented the assignment operator totally wrong.  I have laid out for you the proper way to do copy/assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code

The first is style-based.  There is no need to specify `this->` in all the lines you are referring to the current object.  Doing so muddles the code up and is not necessary.

Second you've written your copy/assignment operators wrong and in bad style.  However, I would give you credit for writing your copy constructor by using the `addAtCurrent` function.  Usually I see persons writing the copy constructor with all sorts of pointer logic, duplicating the code they've already written in the `add` member function they wrote.  You didn't make that mistake, so I commend you for that.

Your copy constructor for `CircularDoubledirectList` does not need to do any `if` statements.  Whenever I see `if` statements in a copy constructor, that sets off a red flag.  If there is too much decision-based logic within a copy constructor, there is a good chance that what you wind up with is not a real copy, but a half-baked copy.  Half-baked copies floating around in a program are bugs that are very hard to find, as it can cause undefined behavior to occur.

So here is a rewrite of the copy constructor without using `if`:

```
template <typename T>
CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::CircularDoubleDirectedList(const CircularDoubleDirectedList &other) : 
                        NodeDirection(other.NodeDirection), 
                        sizeOfList(0), current(nullptr)
{
    Node *counter = other.current;
    for (int x = 0; x < other.sizeOfList; ++x)
    {
        counter = counter->neighbors[BACKWARD];
        addAtCurrent(counter->data);
    }
}
```

The code above makes use of the `member initialization list` to initialize certain members to their "empty" values.  Note that the loop doesn't check for size -- there is no need to.  If the size of `other` is 0, then the loop doesn't execute.

Now given the above, let's rewrite the assignment operator in terms of the copy constructor.  The huge issue with your current implementation of the assignment operator is that you're returning `bool`.  What you should be returning is a reference to a `CircularDoubleDirectedList`.

The second issue with the assignment operator is that it is redundant.  All of that code you wrote is already in the copy constructor.  The way I would fix it is to use the `copy/swap idiom`, where you would be using the copy constructor to "help" with the assignment.

Here is an implementation of using this idiom:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
template <typename T>
class CircularDoubleDirectedList : public ICircularDoubleDirectedList <T>{
private:
    void swap(CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>& left, 
              CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>& right);
//...
};
//...
template <typename T>
void CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::swap(CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>& left, CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>& right)
{
    std::swap(left.NodeDirection, right.NodeDirection);
    std::swap(left.current, right.current);
    std::swap(left.sizeOfList, right.sizeOfList);
}

template <typename T>  
CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>& CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::operator=(const CircularDoubleDirectedList &other)
{
    CircularDoubleDirectedList<T> temp(other);
    swap(*this, temp);
    return *this;
}
```

So what happened here?  Well, all I did was to use the copy constructor to create a temporary object.  Then I called the `swap` function to switch the variables between the temp copy and *this.  Then I return the current object (`this`).  This not only tests the copy constructor, the destructor for `temp` is also tested.  So if there are any bugs in the copy constructor or destructor, you may be able to detect them right here.

I added a `swap` function to call `std::swap` that switches each of the members.

Since your code tests the assignment operator, and you did not implement it correctly with the proper return type, please change your code to the above and test again.

With the changes above, I did not come across any memory corruption issues and the program completed successfully.  Not to say there may not be a bug somewhere (I didn't go through the logic of adding and removing items), but I had no issues running the code after the changes applied to your program was made.

Comment: OH MY GOD DUDE! The world need more people like you! I will study this and try too understand it now that I have a really well explained solution! Again thank you, compiled without any errors and memory leaks!

Comment: @Prolle Thanks.  The trick IMO is that `temp` variable in the assignment operator.  Note that after the swap, `temp` has the pointer that `this` had and `this` has the pointer that `temp` had.  So when `temp` gets destroyed (at the end of the function), it is cleaning up the memory that `this` used to point to, while `this` is now holding onto the memory that `temp` created when it was copy constructed.  Pretty neat.

Comment: Yeah, it was a really smart solution if I may say! One day I might even figure that out myself!! :D